# Get the Scan Operator when releasing documents

Tags: kofax

When releasing documents the scan operator should get logged to a file. I know this is a kofax system variable but how do I get it from the `ReleaseData` object?

Maybe this value is hold by the `Values` collection? What is the key then? I would try to access it by using

`string scanOperator = documentData.Values["?scanOperator?"].Value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kofax's weird naming convention strikes again - during setup, said items are referred to as `BatchVariableNames`. However, during release they are `KFX_REL_VARIABLE`s (an enum named `KfxLinkSourceType`).

Here's how you can add all available items during setup:

```cs
foreach (var item in setupData.BatchVariableNames)
{
    setupData.Links.Add(item, KfxLinkSourceType.KFX_REL_VARIABLE, item);
}
```

The following sample iterates over the `DocumentData.Values` collection, storing each `BatchVariable` in a `Dictionary<string, string>` named `BatchVariables`.

```cs
foreach (Value v in DocumentData.Values)
{
    switch (v.SourceType)
    {
        case KfxLinkSourceType.KFX_REL_VARIABLE:
            BatchVariables.Add(v.SourceName, v.Value);
            break;
    }
}
```

You can then access any of those variables by key - for example `Scan Operator's User ID` yields the scan user's domain and name.

Comment: thanks. But I have one "problem".Kofax' language is set to german so the source name is german too. Do I really have to take the german key? This key would be `Benutzer-ID der Scan-Bedienungsperson`. So for my if statement I would have to take `if (sourceName == "Scan Operator's User ID" || sourceName == "Benutzer-ID der Scan-Bedienungsperson")` but I think this is really ugly ..

Comment: Create a simple batch or index field, hide it, and set its default value to `{Benutzer-ID der Scan-Bedienungsperson}`. Then, instead of using the Kofax value, just use said field.

Comment: well, thanks, that's a solution. But I think they should have used english keys only :)

Comment: If you think that's bad, wait until you see their database naming conventions.